# Conditional slicepipe in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular5

How can I use an conditional slicepipe in an `ngFor`?

Here below the html template:

```
<div *ngFor="let bucket of getBucketsWithValues(bucketName.criterium ? bucketName.criterium : bucketName) | orderBy:'key' 
     | slice:0:bucketName.show_max">
    <osi-checkbox [model]="filter[bucketName.criterium ? bucketName.criterium : bucketName][bucket.key].checked" 
      (change)="onFilterChange(filter[bucketName.criterium ? bucketName.criterium : bucketName][bucket.key], $event.checked)">

        <osi-li-body class="osi-black-87">Test {{ bucket.key }}&nbsp;({{ bucket.doc_count }})</osi-li-body>
    </osi-checkbox>
</div>

<div *ngIf="bucketName.show_max">
  <osi-toggle-show-more-item [openTitle]="'Show more'" [closeTitle]="'Show less'" [padding]="false"></osi-toggle-show-more-item>
</div>
```

So how can I slice the output by the number which represents the `bucketName.show_max`  of the `ngFor` only when `bucketName.show_max` is not null. Otherwise show all the results.

Hope someone could help me out on this issue..

Comment: yes it has a `show_max` property but this is not always set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let bucket of (bucketName.show_max !== null
? (getBucketsWithValues(bucketName.criterium ? bucketName.criterium : bucketName) | orderBy:'key'| slice:0:bucketName.show_max)
: (getBucketsWithValues(bucketName.criterium ? bucketName.criterium : bucketName) | orderBy:'key'))">
    <osi-checkbox [model]="filter[bucketName.criterium ? bucketName.criterium : bucketName][bucket.key].checked" 
      (change)="onFilterChange(filter[bucketName.criterium ? bucketName.criterium : bucketName][bucket.key], $event.checked)">

        <osi-li-body class="osi-black-87">Test {{ bucket.key }}&nbsp;({{ bucket.doc_count }})</osi-li-body>
    </osi-checkbox>
</div>

<div *ngIf="bucketName.show_max">
  <osi-toggle-show-more-item [openTitle]="'Show more'" [closeTitle]="'Show less'" [padding]="false"></osi-toggle-show-more-item>
</div>
```

I think there is no need for an explanation of what is happening.

Comment: I have updated answer, you need to add `()` because pipe `|` symbol   breaks condition syntax